# Would creative commons be good option for bloggers to keep owenership on their contents

Tags: blog, copyright, creative-commons

I just want that if someone use my contents on their site, they should give a link to my site or some credit. For this purpose i just want to go for creative commons licensing.

Would creative commons be good option for bloggers to keep owenership on their contents?

Comment: If you don't license your content explicitly, noone has the right to "use" your contents at all (with some exceptions, depending on country, like citations, use for teachings etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer:

You'd need to select an appropriate [CC license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/).

In all cases attribution is required, you can also restrict commercial usage, the creation of derivative works and (assuming they are allowed) require that derivative works be licensed in the same way.

Regardless of which license you choose, you will retain *copyright* of the content. You merely provide anyone who wants it a free license to reprint (and possibly modify) as long as they abide by terms of the license.

Note however that you cannot revoke the CC license at a later date! Nor can you change to a more restrictive CC license after the fact.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph: You *can* change to a different CC license (or remove the CC license altogether) at any time. But this doesn't affect people that downloaded/used your content (or those following the chain) before that change. In other words: a license change applies only to new/future use of the content *you* publish yourself.